# Getting several data from several tables into one bean

Tags: mysql

Well, the problem is that I have to get only one bean with results from different tables.
All of the fields are numeric.
For example

MATERIALS: IDMAT(PK) , MATERIAL 
SEATS: IDMAT(FK) , IDCLASS(FK) , VALUE
PITCH: IDMAT(FK) , IDCLASS(FK) , NMR , VLR

Table A:

```
IDMAT    MATERIAL
```

Table B:

```
IDMAT    IDCLASS
```

And the TABLE C contains around 8 NMR (with a VLR) for each IDCLASS, and again 4 IDCLASS for each IDMAT.

Now, I am trying with a single query, left outer joining the tables, and getting a lot of rows for each IDMAT, and then I am working with the results
to form only one bean for each material.
It is not the idea, because I am having a lot of problems with the equals method and more things.

This is my query:

```
    select
    M.IDMAT,
    M.MATERIAL,
    S.IDMAT,
    S.IDCLASS,
    S.VALUE,
    P.IDMAT,
    P.IDCLASS,
    P.NMR,
    P.VLR
from MATERIALS M
left outer join SEATS S on S.IDMAT = M.IDMAT
left outer join PITCH P on P.IDMAT = M.IDMAT

order by M.IDMAT
```

DATA IM GETTING:
http://puu.sh/8lBjX.png

DATA IM EXPECTED TO GET:
http://puu.sh/8lBky.png

(sorry for the links but I cant post images)

The question is

How can I do a single query which gives me only one bean for each IDMAT with the different fields from the tables a , b and c?

Tell me if you need more details, or something.

Comment: Yes, we need more details, or something. What are the table structures? Data in these tables? The query you attempted? Anything at all involving code instead of concept.

Comment: Please show a data sample and the results you'd expect from it.

Comment: What you're showing won't work, because you'd get a variable number of columns for each row. Have you tried my answer ?

Comment: Now I am showing a lot of results, but I'm trying to find a way to do the second. That is what I want.

Comment: Have you tried my answer, which results do you get, are you satisfied with it ?

Comment: Yes, I've tried with this. But it doesn't work like I expected. I'm working with my query, and trying to solve the problems in the java code. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `GROUP_CONCAT()` function, which returns a list of values, separated by commas.

```
select
    M.IDMAT,
    M.MATERIAL,
    GROUP_CONCAT(S.IDCLASS),
    GROUP_CONCAT(S.VALUE,
    GROUP_CONCAT(P.NMR),
    GROUP_CONCAT(P.VLR)
from MATERIALS M
left outer join SEATS S on S.IDMAT = M.IDMAT
left outer join PITCH P on P.IDMAT = M.IDMAT
group by M.IDMAT, M.MATERIAL
order by M.IDMAT
```

Becareful, `GROUP_CONCAT()` returns lists of 1024 values maximum by default.